# no wifi adapter found ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, updates, 17.10

I use 2 Operating System on my computer, Ubuntu 17.10 and Windows 10, I do not have any problem with windows but there are some problems with Ubuntu for 2 days.
I can not connect to the internet and there is a red triangle with an exclamation mark and the message :

> The update information is outdated. Thid may be caused by  network
>   problems or by a repository that no longer available. please update
>   manually by selecting 'Show updates' from the indicator menu, and
>   watching for any failing repositories.

I CAN NOT CONNECT TO THE INTERNET

Comment: Please refer to the following link [ubuntu 17.10 - no wi-fi adapter found](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2375901), hope it works.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Also please ignore the above comment. Well-intentioned yet wrong advice. Before anything else we need to identify the hardware which may or may not be the some of the UF link.

Comment: When ı run lspci -knn | grep Net -A3  there is no output

Comment: Is it a USB dongle?

Comment: No it is not a USB dongle

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

It will reinstall the driver for the Broadcom Wireless Card of your laptop.

You might need to reboot after that:  `sudo reboot`